# How do I troubleshoot this error on ubuntu 22.04 for Anaconda?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm getting a Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding Python runtime state: core initialized.

Would someone be able to help me troubleshoot the error? I am at a loss for what to do at this point.

```
conda
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/lib/python3.11'
  sys._base_executable = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/rkt34/anaconda3'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/lib/python311.zip',
    '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/lib/python3.11',
    '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1080, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1504, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1476, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1616, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1659, in _fill_cache
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/home/rkt34/anaconda3/lib/python3.11
```